# Embedded Binaries in Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods, podspec

Is it somehow possible to embed a framework/binary in cocoapod?
Didn't find any find on the internet.

The source code of this binary/framework shouldn't be visible, for the users of the pod

The option of embedding a binary is just lacking in cocoapod build.

Comment: If you deliver your pod with sources, use_frameworks! option create dynamic framework target in Pods project and automatically embed it in linked app targets.

Comment: Unfortunately the source code shouldn't be visible. It's like a pod with a framework, which is a blackbox

Answer (score 3):

add `s.vendored_frameworks ='XXXX.framework'`(your framework) in your podspec file,

It worked to me!

Comment: I didn't work for me, so I wanted to do it manually, but there is no filed "embedded binaries" in cocoapod build settings section

Comment: CocoaPods embed frameworks using shell script inside Pods/Target Support files directory.